# How to prevent logs getting loaded multiple times from logstash

Tags: logstash

I a newbie in ELk. I want to load the logs only once from logstash, again if run the config file the logs should not be read. And in the input plugin if i dont give `start_position="beginning"` the log will not load once also. and if I give `start_position="beginning"`, each time I run conf file, the logs keeps on loading.  Also tried with `start_position="beginning", ignore_older=>0` this time logs are not loading not even once.

Comment: Are you using a file input? Have you set sincedb_path?

Comment: yeah I am using the file input, No I havent set the sincedb_path

Comment: input {
        file{
               
               path => "/root/json-data/sample-json.log"
               
      }
}